# Roslyn get IdentifierName in ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Currently I am working on simple code analyse for c# with roslyn. I need to parse all document of all projects inside one solution and getting the declared used classes inside this document.

For example from:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

I want to get `Program` uses `Foo`.

I already parse all documents and get the declared class inside.

```
// all projects in solution
foreach (var project in _solution.Projects)
{
    // all documents inside project
    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
        var model = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
        var classes = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
        // all classes inside document
        foreach (var classDeclarationSyntax in classes)
        {
            var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclarationSyntax);
            var objectCreationExpressionSyntaxs = classDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>();
            // all object creations inside document
            foreach (var objectCreationExpressionSyntax in objectCreationExpressionSyntaxs)
            {
                // TODO: Get the identifier value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is to get the IdentifierName `Foo`. Using the [debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Vtf.png), I see `objectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type`got the `Identifier.Text` got the value I need, but `objectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type.Identifier`seems to be private.

I could use the `SymbolFinder` to find all references of a Class in the solution. As I already need to parse all documents its should work without.

Maybe I am on the wrong path? How to get the identifier value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to handle the different types of `TypeSyntax`es. See here: http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/TypeSyntax.cs,29171ac4ad60a546,references

What you see in the debugger is a `SimpleNameSyntax`, which does have a public `Identifier` property.

**Update**

```
var ns = objectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type as NameSyntax;
if (ns != null)
{
  return ns.Identifier.ToString();
}

var pts = objectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type as PredefinedTypeSyntax;
if (pts != null)
{
  return pts.Keyword.ToString();
}

...
```

All other subtypes would need to be handed. Note that `ArrayType.ElementType` is also a `TypeSyntax`, so you would most probably need to make this method recursive.

Comment: Ok, how to do this? Your link did not really help me to understand this. Could you explain more or use some code please?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks. Maybe a better solution as the one @Crowcoder posted. Will figure out witch one will fits my need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the identifier from the syntax's Type property:

```
foreach (var objectCreationExpressionSyntax in objectCreationExpressionSyntaxs)
{
    IdentifierNameSyntax ins = (IdentifierNameSyntax)objectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type;
    var id = ins.Identifier;
    Console.WriteLine(id.ValueText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exact what i needed. I did got this before but didnt know that i need to cast to `IdentifierNameSyntax`

Answer (score 1):

Strings can be misleading.

Let's say you have the expression `new SomeClass()`, and you get the string "SomeClass" out of it. How do you know if that refers to `Namespace1.SomeClass` or `Namespace2.SomeClass` ? What if there is a `using SomeClass = Namespace3.SomeOtherType;` declaration being used?

Fortunately, you don't have to do this analysis yourself. The compiler can bind the ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax to a symbol. You have your semantic model, use it.

```
foreach (var oce in objectCreationExpressionSyntaxs)
{
    ITypeSymbol typeSymbol = model.GetTypeInfo(oce).Type;
    // ...
}
```

You can compare this symbol with the symbols you get from `model.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclarationSyntax)`, just make sure you use the `Equals` method, not the `==` operator.